# Extend Class or Create a Category to Customize Existing Frameworks?

Tags: objective-c, class, oop, objective-c-category

I need to customize some methods and properties of existing classes from some third-party framework. I know that I can extend the class or create a Category. But which approach works better if I want to keep the source of framework **untouched** and only create my own additions/extensions?

In my particular case, I want to retrieve a private property of class `SomeClass:NSObject` declared in .m file as:

**SomeClass.m**

```
@interface SomeClass() 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string;
//...
@end

@implementation SomeClass 
//....
@end
```

Comment: When you say "extend", do you mean "subclass"? Class extensions have a particular meaning in ObjC.

Comment: Yes, I mean subclass: CustomView:UIView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a category. A category will work for all subclasses of the class, and not merely for your one subclass. For example, say that you want to be able to get a UIImage of an arbitrary UIView. If you subclass UIView, and then want to use the method on a UIScrollView, you won't be able to use the method without making another subclass for UIScrollView, and every other class in the hierarchy you want to use the method on.

Another reason not to use a subclass is that if you have a method in your framework which returns an instance of a class such as

+(classWithAPrivateProperty*) getClassWithPrivateProperty

you'll have to make a new member of your subclass with the data from that class before you can access the property.

Comment: So with category MyCategory+SomeClass I can just access SomeClass's private variable by creating a method in MyCategory+SomeClass to pull this variable and never modify anything in the SomeClass, as I understand correctly. Right?

Comment: However, accessing private variable in Category results in linker error. You should use a trick such as return [self valueForKey:@"varFromSomClass"]; in categories method. Not sure if this is perfectly legal but it does work as expected.